# GNUplot surface using a predefined color map

Tags: gnuplot, surface, colormap

My data file is a 9800x128 matrix of floating point values, and I'm having trouble plotting a surface graph, that should look similar to MATLABs surf() plot.

Using:

```
splot '/directory/data.txt' every ::1:1 matrix with lines
```

works fine, but everything is in one color which makes it impossible to see what's going on. The color palette that I've imported is:

```
set palette defined (0 0 0 0.5, 1 0 0 1, 2 0 0.5 1, 3 0 1 1, 4 0.5 1 0.5, 5 1 1 0, 6 1 0.5 0, 7 1 0 0, 8 0.5 0 0)
```

Which is similar to the default one used in MATLAB. Drawing just a 2D contour using this palette:

```
plot '/directory/data.txt' matrix notitle with image
```

works just fine as well, it's as soon as I try to marry the color map with a surface plots, as follows:

splot '/directory/data.txt' every ::1:1 matrix with image

I get the following warning message and I'm left with an empty plot.

```
warning: Number of pixels cannot be factored into integers matching grid. N = 1244473  K = 762
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your data is saved as matrix format, i.e. arranged as

```
z00 z10 z20 z30 ...
z01 z11 z21 z31 ...
z02 z12 z22 z32 ...
z03 z13 z23 z33 ...
...
```

then you can plot you data with

```
set palette defined (0 0 0 0.5, 1 0 0 1, 2 0 0.5 1, 3 0 1 1, 4 0.5 1 0.5, 5 1 1 0, 6 1 0.5 0, 7 1 0 0, 8 0.5 0 0)
splot 'data.txt' matrix with pm3d
```